# Why is apt-get the norm instead of apt?

Tags: apt, package-management

Why do people use `apt-get` instead of `apt`?

In nearly every tutorial I see, the suggestion is to use `apt-get`.

`apt` is prettier (by default), shorter, and generally more intuitive. (`apt-cache search` vs `apt search`, for example)

I don't know if I'm missing something because `apt` just seems better in every way. What's the argument for `apt-get` over `apt` for everyday use?

Comment: I didn't even know there was a program named **apt**. So, learning something. However, did we really need another program? We already had **dpkg**, **apt-get**, **aptitude** and all those graphical programs such as **Apper**, **Synaptic** etc. What does **apt** really add?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `apt` front-end is a recent addition, it was added in version 1.0 in April 2014. So it's only been part of one Debian stable release, Debian 8. People who've used Debian for longer are used to `apt-get` and `apt-cache`, and old habits die hard — and old tutorials die harder (and new users learn old habits from those).

`apt` is nicer for end users as a command-line tool, although even there it has competition — I prefer `aptitude` for example. As a general-purpose tool though it's not necessarily ideal, because its interface is explicitly not guaranteed to stay the same from one release to the next, and it's not designed for use in scripts. Thus in any circumstance where instructions may be used in a script, it should be avoided; so it's typically safer to suggest `apt-get` rather than `apt` in answers on Unix.SE and similar sites.

Comment: So, essentially, the purpose of the suggestion of apt-get (outside of scripts) is more of a sort of "fail-safe" in case something were to change in a new release of apt, aptitude, etc?

Comment: Thank you both for your thorough answers. It's much appreciated. That tidbit about apt appearing in Jessie was interesting and news to me as well.

Comment: Yes, it's a fail-safe, and also a reflex — I know I tend to just use `apt-get` out of habit. It avoid having to ask what version of Debian (or a derivative) the user has, and what the intended usage is. If you tell someone to use `apt-get`, it will work everywhere `apt` is available, and is safe, so you don't need to list the caveats every time; if you tell someone to use `apt`, you have to say "but you'll need to use `apt-get` instead if ...". So it's easier to just mention `apt-get`. (We do see `apt` more and more in answers here, so things do change.)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, apt is a high level user friendly utilities set to operate with dpkg.
 
So, it was divided to several packages, where aptitude was the most automated package. I do think that the background was - several development teams, where each of them proposed own ideology. Now, somebody joined all these products into one apt tool, that (as I suppose) can be decrypted as something like Automated Package Tools and goes to Debian Linux thread development team basic concept.
So, if you need to have low-level control, use dpkg and all manual concerning to it. 
At the same time, you can use any of apt-* tools or aptitude if you do not want to care about dependencies. Or apt, as Stephen said, appeared in Jessie (I didn't even know about that)